# InStr function text delimiter issue in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the code as below and it's almost perfect, however it has one little flaw.

```
SELECT instr (1, "n123456 (name lastname)", "(")+1 AS [First Char], 
instr (1, "n123456 (name lastname)", ")")-1 AS [Last Char], 
mid("n123456 (name lastname)", instr (1, "n123456 (name lastname)",
"(")+1,instr (1, "n123456 (name lastname)", ")")) AS [text];
```

So it returns the following values:

> - [First Char] = 10
> - [Last Char] = 22
> - [text] = name lastname)

I can't figure out how to remove that last bracket from the string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mid function syntax is

```
Mid ( text, start_position, number_of_characters )
```

The number of characters you are specifying is wrong. It should be Your `([LastChar]-1) - [First Char]`

Try below code

```
SELECT instr (1, "n123456 (name lastname)", "(")+1 AS [First Char], 
instr (1, "n123456 (name lastname)", ")")-1 AS [Last Char], 
mid("n123456 (name lastname)", instr (1, "n123456 (name lastname)", "(")+1,
instr (1, "n123456 (name lastname)", ")")-2 -
instr (1, "n123456 (name lastname)", "(")+1) AS [text];
```

The o/p is

[image: O/P]